# Algum tipo de colisão se aplicaria neste caso?

Tags: construct-2

Tenho dois objetos que se movem juntos('colados')no mapa, ambos seguindo o movimento do mouse. Um dos objetos cresce ao coletar pequenas 'coisas', ao fazer isso o outro objeto começa a sobrepor o objeto que está crescendo. Aí está o problema.

Ambos os objetos têm as behaviors: BoundToLayout + Pin + Bullet + Solid.

O que faço para que um objeto não sobreponha o outro?

Comment: Bem vindo, veja [como criar um exemplo Mínimo, 
Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Eu não conheço em detalhes o Construct 2. Mas ajudaria se vc explicasse o que esses behaviours fazem. Provavelmente algum desses behaviours é o responsável por fazer o objeto "crescer". Nesse caso, o que vc pode fazer é calcular a distância entre os dois objetos e afastar o que cresce do outro proporcionalmente ao tanto que ele cresce. É mais prático, mais computacionalmente eficiente, e gera resultados potencialmente melhores do que usar um colisor.

Comment: E, como bem disse o colega @rubStackOverflow, se você fornecer (para download, com um link para o Dropbox, por exemplo) um exemplo de projeto mínimo que reproduza o problema, facilita enormemente para que alguém que tenha o Construct instalado possa se interessar em testar e te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se entendi exatamente o problema, mas segue um exemplo bem simples,
utilizando a lógica indicada no comentário do @LuizVieira, que eu acredito que seja a
mais eficiente para este caso (sem a necessidade de uso de *Behaviors*):

---

O primeiro objeto (`obj1`) segue as coordenadas do mouse, portanto a cada event *tick* a sua
posição é atualizada conforme o comando:

`Set position to (Mouse.X, Mouse.Y)`

Neste mesmo evento, adicionei uma *action* que aumenta o tamanho do `obj1`
em função do tempo `dt*10` (para simular o crecimento do objeto):

`Set size to (obj1.Width + dt*10, obj1.Height + dt*10)`

Como a posição do objeto 2 (`obj2`) deve seguir o `obj1`, a posição
deste objeto deve estar relacionada com as propriedades `obj1.X` e `obj1.Y`.

Para manter o `obj2` afastado do `obj1` em função do tamanho, uma
possibilidade é adicionar a soma desses tamanhos à posição do
`obj2` (neste exemplo, apenas no eixo `X`):

`Set position to (obj1.X + obj1.Width/2 + obj2.Width/2, obj1.Y)`

Simplificando o cálculo da posição `X`, é possível eliminar uma divisão:

`Set position to (obj1.X + (obj1.Width + obj2.Width)/2, obj1.Y)`

O *Event sheet* fica dessa forma:

[image: Event sheet para a descição acima]

E o resultado final:

[image: Resultado da animação]

---

**Atualização (em resposta ao comentário):**

O objeto `obj2` (objeto que sobrepõe) está conectado ao `obj1` através do *behavior* `Pin`.

- Uma possibilidade para solucionar o problema, é retirar o *behavior* `Pin` do `obj2` e atualizar
  sua posição "manualmente" com o comando `Set position to`, sempre que houver movimento do `obj1` (conforme a resposta acima).

- Outra solução possível, é alterar a posição do `obj2` com o *behavior* `Pin` desabilitado em todas as *actions*  onde houverem alterações de tamanho do `obj1`. Após alterar a posição do `obj2`, habilitar novamente o `Pin`.

Após aplicar a segunda sugestão no exemplo acima, o *Event sheet* fica da seguinte forma:

[image: Event sheet da segunda sugestão]

Comment: Oi.
Obrigado por responder!
Eu tentei usar o que você falou, mas não deu certo... Eu acho que é por que uso um 'sistema' diferente para fazer o obj1 crescer. Bem, abaixo eu coloquei o link para uma imagem do sistema que eu estou usando, se você puder me ajudar a aplicar nele o que você falou, eu agradeceria muito!

https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-B6DzlEho52s/VtYwbMxEwJI/AAAAAAAAAfM/Zk4kdD1Uwe0/s1600/sistema.JPG

Comment: Oi! Acredito que agora eu entendi o problema. O `obj2` está "ligado" ao `obj1` através do *behavior* `Pin`, é isso?

Comment: Sim. Exatamente.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta! Espero que ajude a solucionar o problema :)

Comment: Olá.
Tentei várias vezes, mas ainda não conseguir...
Abaixo eu coloquei o modo como estou fazendo,e uns pequenos cometários.

imagem1: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-v-QU2OEQOic/VtdBNXRh21I/AAAAAAAAAfc/YNJ3Q0iBlqw/s1600/imagem1.JPG
Configuração original, sem uso do Every tick, onde o Obj1 cresce ao colidir/destruir algo, add para ele 1 ponto. Uso então uma Instance Variable chamada pontos1. No Obj1, eu uso o Set Bullet of motion to angle(Self.X, Self.Y, Mouse.X,Mouse.Y), por que o Set position dá um erro onde o Obj1 e Objt2 seguem o mouse muito, muito rápido, não seguindo a velocidade estipulada.

Comment: Imagem2: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-nqfbvoSU2HY/VtdBlimRlDI/AAAAAAAAAfg/bKYXfcRAMtU/s1600/imagem2.JPG
Esta é a maneira que estou aplicando o que você falou. Ao invés de Obj1.Width, estou colocando Obj1.pontos1, já que é esta variável que faz o Obj1 crescer. Também tirei a virgula /2, e coloquei um sinal de /2 +, pois com a virgula está dando erro. Será que tenho de criar alguma variável para o Obj2, para colocar no lugar do .Width?

Comment: Vi o projeto, não há necessidade de criar uma nova variável e também não precisa acrescentar o evento `Every tick`. Em todos os lugares onde tiver um `Set size to` do `obj1`, você pode acrescentar a sequência de *actions* (`obj2`) do exemplo (logo abaixo desse `Set size`): `Unpin`, `Set position` exatamente igual ao do exemplo 2 (não precisa colocar o `pontos`), `Pin`de novo. Pelo *Event sheet* do seu projeto, você precisa fazer essa alteração em 4 lugares (Eventos 26, 27, 30 e 31). Por favor, me avise se deu certo :)