# Como fazer dois objetos manter sempre a mesma distância um do outro?

Tags: construct-2

Ambos os objetos se movimentam paralelamente pelo mapa.

Tentei usar a função Lerp, mas não consigo fazer com que funcione. Como usar corretamente essa função?

Answer (score 1):

Como os dois objetos se movimentam paralelamente e sempre a mesma distância,
acredito que a solução mais simples seja altarar diretamente a posição do
segundo objeto conforme a posição do primeiro, mais uma distância de *offset*.

Segue um exemplo simplificado:

O objeto `sp1` segue as coordenadas do mouse (a cada evento *tick*):

`Set position to (Mouse.X, Mouse.Y)`

No mesmo evento, você adiciona uma *action* alterando a posição do
objeto `sp2` para uma distância fixa de a partir da posição de `sp1`
(neste exemplo, 150 unidades no eixo `X`):

`Set position to (sp1.X + 150, sp1.Y)`

O *Event sheet* fica assim:

[image: Imagem do event sheet com as funções implementadas]

---

A função `lerp` calcula uma [interpolação linear](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpola%C3%A7%C3%A3o_linear) entre 2 pontos, e pode ser
utilizada, por exemplo, para suavizar o movimento de um objeto:

`lerp(a, b, x)`

Para a chamada de função acima, ela retorna o valor de `a + x*(b-a)`.

No exemplo, se você substituir o comando no *action* do objeto `sp2` por:

`Set position to (lerp(sp1.X, sp1.X + 300, 0.5), sp1.Y)`

Irá obter exatamente o mesmo efeito, porém, com um custo maior de processamento.

Comment: Olá. Obrigado por responder.

Ah, uma outra coisa: caso um dos objetos aumente de tamanho com o tempo, como eu faria para que a distância entre eles ainda continuasse sempre a mesma?

Comment: @DeividsGomes: Oi! Ontem, eu respondi uma pergunta parecida: [Algum tipo de colisão se aplicaria neste caso?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115529/algum-tipo-de-colis%C3%A3o-se-aplicaria-neste-caso). Acredito que possa ajudar :)